# Cout subtract the output in simple print

Tags: c++, printing, cout

When I use cout to print the value of my variable, it doesn't give me the same answer if I use two statements in one line or two lines. Can you help me?

```
int a= 5;
cout << a << endl;
cout << a-- << endl;

cout << a << a-- << endl; 
// it gives me different answer, why?
//they are basically same thing
```

Comment: Order of operations.  The one-line example is a bad idea in practice, but I see how this is an interesting theoretical question.

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04, g++ v7.3.0 (c++17)  reports:  warning: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

Comment: Simply put, its common to assume that things go from left to right in `cout << a << a-- << endl;` but it's not true, so your two examples are not the same. (until you get to C++ 17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no guarantees of evaluation order prior to C++17 with `operator <<`, but since" C++17, left to right order is guarantee for `operator <<`.

See [eval_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. The link was helpful

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << a << a-- << endl;
```

is translated as:

```
cout.operator<<(a).operator<<(a--).operator<<(endl);
```

In such a case, the language does not guarantee which of the arguments will be evaluated first. A compiler is free to choose whichever evaluation order makes sense to them. Please note that the function call order is guaranteed but not the evaluation order of the function arguments.

If you are able to use [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), the standard has changed for the `<<` operator. It guarantees an evaluation order that makes sense and you will get the expected result.

Comment: Got you. Thanks for clarifiction